# Merging the `enter` selectin into the `update` selections

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[D3 documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-enter) says:

> The enter selection merges into the update selection when you append
>   or insert. This approach reduces code duplication between enter and
>   update. Rather than applying operators to both the enter and update
>   selection separately, you can now apply them to the update selection
>   after entering the nodes. In the rare case that you want to run
>   operators only on the updating nodes, you can run them on the update
>   selection before entering new nodes.

I don't understand the meaning of the phrase `merge into` in the first sentence. Can someone explain this bit? (Perhaps I'm missing a connection with some standard database terminology?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that after you've applied an `append` or `insert` operation to the `enter` selection, its elements will be part of the `update` selection. That is, you increase the size of the `update` selection. The purpose of this is, as the documentation says, to reduce code duplication. After appending a new element, various attributes have to set (e.g. size, color, position). The same attributes have to be set for elements that are updated in many cases and the same code can be used.

The database equivalent would be selecting rows from different tables (`enter` and `update`) and then applying some operation to the rows selected from `enter` to add them to `update`. This analogy doesn't work entirely, but it may help you understand what's going on.

Comment: But `enter` doesn't return the `update` set, correct? So if I chain like this: `d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(dataset).enter().append("p").text(function(d){return d;});` I'm only working on the `enter` set?

Comment: Yes. You'll still have to save the update selection if you want to operate on that.

Comment: I didn't get this until I saw your answer, and edited the docs wiki to try to make it clearer. Can't guarantee the changes will stick, but I tried.